# Need oneliner to insert character after Nth occurrence of delimiter on 2nd line in unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Hello I need oneliner to insert character after Nth occurrence of delimiter on 2nd line in unix; The criteria are these.

1. Find position of nth occurrence of the delimiter.
2. Insert character after the nth occurrence.
3. This is on the 2nd line only.

**Note:** I am doing this in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

#### INPUT FILE

```
1 foo bar base
2 foo bar base
```

#### CODE

```
awk 'NR==2{$2=$2"X"; print}' file
```

- you can specify a delimiter with `-F`
- `NR` to specify the line we work on
- `$2` is the 2th value separated by space (in this case)
- `$2=$2"X"` is a concatenation
- `print` alone print the entire line

#### OUTPUT

```
2 fooX bar base
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the input file:

```
$ cat file
1 foo bar base
2 foo bar base
```

To insert the character X after the 3rd occurrence of the delimiter space, use:

```
$ sed -r '2 s/([^ ]* ){3}/&X/' file
1 foo bar base
2 foo bar Xbase
```

To make the change to the file in place, use sed's `-i` option:

```
sed -i -r '2 s/([^ ]* ){3}/&X/' file
```

#### How it works

Consider the `sed` command:

```
2 s/([^ ]* ){3}/&X/
```

The initial `2` instructs `sed` to apply this command only to the second line.

We are using the `s` or *substitute* command.  This command has the form `s/old/new/` where old and new are:

- `old` is the regular expression `([^ ]* ){3}`.  This matches everything up to and including the third occurrence of space.
- `new` is the replacement text, `&X`.  The ampersand refers to what we matched in `old`, which is all the line up to and including the third space.  The `X` is the new character that we are inserting.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '2s/X/&Y/3' file
```

This inserts `Y` after the third occurence of `X` on the second line only.